# Kill an app process from the library project

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, library-project, gradle-dependencies

I am developing an Android library project which can be integrated to an app via a gradle dependency.

As a requirement I need to kill the app process from inside the library project.

I am using the following code to do that. But what I have noticed is that it kills the library project process but not the app process.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Any way or ways for achieving this?

EDIT:
This has to be done at the library project level. Not from the client app level.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Service class in main app.

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         someMethod();
         return START_STICKY;
    }
    public void someMethod(){
      android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

and in your lib class use this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName("my service class path"));
startService(intent);
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: From the main app you can do this. But when the library is imported via a gradle dependency you cannot rely on the app which uses that library do this.

Comment: i know from library you cannot access any activity. but you can get the getApplication() instance of the app. and then you can call  the app.someMethod().

Comment: You cannot instruct the client app developer to add the kill method to the application class, can you? I'll edit the question again to add that this has to be done without intervention of the client app.

Comment: Thanks. My question is how to do this without doing anything to the client app.